# Autotools no symbols in library

Tags: c, automake, libtool

Autotools (LIBTOOL) build failing to add symbols to shared library. This is for postgis, please find below the Automake file.

```
AR = ar rs

CC = @CC@
LIBLWGEOM_LDFLAGS = ../../liblwgeom/.libs/liblwgeom.lcona
LIBLWGEOM_CFLAGS = -I../../liblwgeom
LIBGDAL_CFLAGS = @LIBGDAL_CFLAGS@
LIBGDAL_LDFLAGS = @LIBGDAL_LDFLAGS@
GEOS_LDFLAGS = @GEOS_LDFLAGS@ -lgeos_c
PROJ_LDFLAGS = @PROJ_LDFLAGS@ -lproj
LDFLAGS = $(LIBLWGEOM_LDFLAGS) $(LIBGDAL_LDFLAGS) $(PROJ_LDFLAGS) $(GEOS_LDFLAGS)
CFLAGS = @CFLAGS@ @PICFLAGS@ @WARNFLAGS@ $(LIBLWGEOM_CFLAGS) $(LIBGDAL_CFLAGS) @PROJ_CPPFLAGS@ @GEOS_CPPFLAGS@

top_builddir = @top_builddir@
prefix = @prefix@
exec_prefix = @exec_prefix@
libdir = @libdir@
includedir = @includedir@
SHELL = @SHELL@
INSTALL = $(SHELL) ../install-sh
LIBTOOL = @LIBTOOL@

SOVER = @POSTGIS_MAJOR_VERSION@.@POSTGIS_MINOR_VERSION@.@POSTGIS_MICRO_VERSION@


# Standalone RTCORE objects
RT_OBJS = \
    rt_util.o \
    rt_spatial_relationship.o \
    rt_mapalgebra.o \
    rt_geometry.o \
    rt_statistics.o \
    rt_pixel.o \
    rt_warp.o \
    rt_band.o \
    rt_raster.o \
    rt_serialize.o \
    rt_wkb.o \
    rt_context.o

RT_LIB = librtcore.la
RT_HEADERS = \
    rt_serialize.h \
    librtcore.h \
    librtcore_internal.h \
    ../raster_config.h

LT_RT_OBJS = $(RT_OBJ:.o=.lo)
LT_OBJ = $(LT_RT_OBJ)



all: librtcore.la

install: install-librtcore

uninstall: uninstall-librtcore

install-librtcore: librtcore.la
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=install $(INSTALL) librtcore.la "$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/librtcore.la"
    $(INSTALL) librtcore.h "$(DESTDIR)$(includedir)/librtcore.h"

unisntall-librtcore:
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode-uninstall rm -f "$(DESTDIR)$(libdir)/liblrtcore.la"


librtcore.la: $(LT_RT_OBJS)
    $(LIBTOOL) --tag=CC --mode=link $(CC) -rpath $(libdir) $(LT_RT_OBJS) -release $(SOVER) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@


$(LT_RT_OBJS): %.lo : %.c
    $(LIBTOOL) --mode=compile $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -f $(RT_OBJS)
    rm -f $(RT_LIB)
    rm -f librtcore.la
    rm -rf .libs

distclean: clean
    rm -f Makefile
```

When trying to link against the shared library, I get the following error

undefined reference to `rtdealloc' This is my first experience with autotools.

Answer (score 0):

rtdealloc is defined in module rt_context.c historically.  Are you missing this file from your sources?  I don't see it listed in the object files.